# How can I use identifier as a query parameter in api-platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I am using api-platform 2.6 with symfony 6. I have a model

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;

#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'path' => '',
        ],
    ]
)]
class SomeName
{
    #[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
    public string $pathInfo;
```

$pathInfo is a identifier and can take values of the form like "/some/path/.../". I would like to use this api method like

```
/some-name/?pathInfo=/some/path/.../
```

where $pathInfo is a query (GET) parameter. How can I do this?

I have tried this

```
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'path' => '?pathInfo={pathInfo}',
        ],
    ],
```

but I get error "No route found for..." and I don't like that in OpenApi documentation this api method looks like "/some-name?pathInfo={pathInfo}"

Answer (score 0):

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;

#[ApiResource(
    itemOperations: [
        'get' => [
            'path' => '/some-name',
            'openapi_context' => [
                'parameters' => [
                    [
                        'in' => 'query',
                        'name' => 'pathInfo',
                        'required' => true,
                        'schema' => [
                            'type' => 'string',
                        ],
                        'description' => 'The path information',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
)]
```

Comment: This just outputs the second pathInfo field in the Open Api documentation. And the api method itself returns an error "Invalid identifier value or configuration.". But thanks for the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).